# FunctionContinuous produces False for a continuous integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In V 13 on Windows 10 the command (I blow on cold water with  `GenerateConditions -> True`)

```
FunctionContinuous[Integrate[x^n, {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals, 
GenerateConditions -> True], n, Reals]
```

results in `False` which is not correct in view of

```
FunctionContinuous[{x^n, x >= 1 && x <= 2}, {n, x}, Reals]
```

> `True`

and the well-known theorem about the integral depending on a parameter (e.g. see theorem 3.2  [here](https://ocw.uc3m.es/matematicas/calculus-ii/C2/unit3.pdf) ). The false answer is implied by the following: `FunctionContinuous` deals with the result of

```
Integrate[x^n, {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> n > Reals,  GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `(-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n)`

which has a removable singularity at `n==-1`, not with the integral under consideration. I find such incorrect behavior of `FunctionContinuous` for many other integrals depending on a parameter.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: It sounds like your issue is with Integrate.

Comment: @chuy: Thank you for your interest. This is not any issue of me, but the wrong result of `FunctionContinuous` and `FunctionAnalytic` for many integrals. Constructive  and rich-in-content remarks and answers are welcome.

Comment: Another example is `FunctionContinuous[{Integrate[Exp[-a*x]*(Cos[x]^2)^n, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   Assumptions -> a > -Infinity && n >= 1], 
  n >= 1 && a > -Infinity}, {n, a}, Reals]`.

Comment: Sounds like you want FunctionContinuous to hold its first argument (which it currently does not).  File a suggestion with Wolfram would be my constructive advice.

Comment: @chuy: Sorry, don't understand it (What do you mean by "its first argument"?). Can you elaborate your comment?

Comment: `In[537]:= Integrate[x^n, {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals,
  GenerateConditions -> True]

Out[537]= (-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n)` is discontinuous due to singularity at `n=-1`. So the result is correct for the input provided. The remarks by @chuy seem to be quite on target. Though I do not know whether holding the first argument and analysing integrands would be feasible or otherwise aligned with the design of `FunctionContinuous`.

Comment: @DanielLigchtblau: Thank you for your interest. The result of `Integrate[x^n, {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals, 
GenerateConditions -> True]` is generic. It should be `Piecewise[{{(-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n), n!=-1},{Log[2],True}}]` instead of. The latter is the complete answer.

Comment: `FunctionContinuous[
 Piecewise[{{(-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n), n != -1}, {Log[2], 
    True}}], n, Reals]` returns `True`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:  I'd like to repeat that the singularity of `(-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n)` at `n==-1` is removable.

Comment: Pro tip: using "@" won't work if you misspell the name.

Comment: @chuy: What do you mean by "its first argument"?

Comment: Fair point. For better or worse this is a design decision. From the documentation page for `FunctionContinuous`, Possible Issues section first example: "A function needs to be defined everywhere to be continuous:
In[1]:= FunctionContinuous[Sin[x]/x, x] In[2]:= FunctionContinuous[{Sin[x]/x, x != 0}, x]

Out[2]= True`. So I guess this falls into the "it's not a bug, it's a feature" category. (Oh well.)
Out[1]= False"

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I'd like to repeat that `Integrate[x^n, {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals,   GenerateConditions -> True]` produces no warning and no conditional expression. This is a very simple case.

Comment: A more complicated case is `Integrate[x^n, {x, 1, 2}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals,   GenerateConditions -> True]` which results in a long output (`Indeterminate` for `a==2&&n==2` ) without any warning and condition.

Comment: I not aware of any warnings or conditions for `Integrate` to generate for this example.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I don't find in the documentation any description of such behavior  of the definite integral depending on a parameter.

Comment: What different result were you expecting? What warnings or conditions?

Comment: As is written in my above comment, `Piecewise[{{(-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n), n!=-1},{Log[2],True}}]` is a complete answer. Another variants are `ConditionalExpession[ (-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n), n!= -1]` and  `(-1 + 2^(1 + n))/(1 + n)` with a warning "This result is generic".

Comment: This is a limitation of `Integrate`, not `FunctionContinuous`, that has been documented from [Version 1 (p. 499)](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/3.5.6.pdf) until now in [V13.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRll5.png). It's one of the first things I remember learning about Mathematica 30+ years ago: Symbolic solvers find results that are true only generically for parameters.

Comment: @MichaelE2: This is about indefinite integrals. I don't find  a similar for definite integrals in the documentation. BTW,  definite integrals may be calculated not through  the Newton-Leibniz formula (think of contour integrals).

Comment: @MichaelE2: I'd like to quote an example from the documentation : `Integrate[x^n, {x, 0, 1}]` produces `ConditionalExpression[1/(1 + n), Re[n] > -1]`. Also "You miss the point, based on technical distinction that does not make any substantial difference" is not documented, this is your personal opinion.

Comment: Fair enough....The genericity of results is still true in general.

Comment: As you already noted, the singularity at `n==-1` is removable. Removing it gives `log(2)`. That does not require a warning. Anyway, I voted to close this as being documented behavior of `FunctionContinuous`, mostly because closing is easier than endlessly arguing in circles (or topologically equivalent contours, since we are discussing a definite integral).

Comment: Regarding the integration from 0 to 1, that proviso is issues because otherwise the integral won't converge. Which is a very different situation from a discrete (and in this case removable) singularity.

Comment: @DanielLichblau: "Removing it gives log(2). That does not require a warning" is your personal opinion. The question may be closed, but the problem remains.

Comment: My opinion is not the last word, I'll grant you that. And indeed we are considering accounting better for discrete sets of singularities and related. All the same, when it comes to Mathematica's `Integrate`, or symbolic definite integration in general, my view counts for a lot. Suffice it to say that it would be better characterized as a "professional" rather than "personal" opinion.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: There is a room for the improvement here. For example, `Integrate[Exp[a*x^2], {x, -1, 1}, GenerateConditions -> True]` produces `(2 E^a DawsonF[Sqrt[a]])/Sqrt[a]` which is not applicable for `a==0`. BTW, `Integrate[Exp[a*x^2], {x, -1, 1}]` performs `(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfi[Sqrt[a]])/Sqrt[a]` which  is not applicable for `a==0` too.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is some consideration for future handling that might account for discrete sets of singular values of parameters. I do not know offhand whether or to what extent such changes will actually be made. It's a thorny area.

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of `Integrate`, not `FunctionContinuous`. The result of `Integrate` is not continuous. This limitation has been documented from [Version 1 (p. 499)](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/3.5.6.pdf),

[image]

through [V13.0.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html#29727):

[image]

It's one of the first things I remember learning about Mathematica 30+ years ago: Symbolic solvers find results that are true only generically for parameters. The implication is that a user wishing to use Mathematica to problems in analysis might have to apply their intelligence in order to complete their solution.

The approach below won't work in all cases, but it works here because of the results of `Integrate` and `Limit` (and perhaps because of improvements to `Limit` since whenever it has been able to generate the needed conditional expression here) as well as the form of the condition. A user who wishes analyze other functions is at liberty to do so on their own.

```
Limit[
  Integrate[x^k, {x, 1, 2}],
  k -> n,
  GenerateConditions -> True, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Reals] /.
 ConditionalExpression[e_, c_] :> 
  Piecewise[{{e, c}}~
    Join~({Limit[e, n -> #], n == #} & /@ SolveValues[Not[c], n])]
FunctionContinuous[%, n, Reals]

(*  True  *)
```

*P.S.*
The OP objected to the citations in the documentation because the OP's integral is definite whereas the example in the docs is indefinite.  I thought this was a specious distinction, but the OP kindly supplied one example, the same integral but from `0` to `1`.  Then @DanielLichtblau pointed out that conditions are generated because the integral fails to converge for some values of `n`, whereas that is not the case for the OP's integral from `1` to `2`. Instead, in the OP's case we get a generically valid result under the silent assumption that `n` has a "generic" value, that is in this case, `n != -1`, just as indicated in the documentation. One might wish that Mathematica did and was able to compute according to a precise mathematical analysis. I, for one, am glad it often finishes successfully in time to get home by dinner time.

Comment: One may wish that results of things like `Integrate[x^k, {x, -1, t}]` were completely accurate, and perhaps someday they will be. They are documented, though. At least that's how I've understood the documentation.